# Reassigning database ID subject strings into factors in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr, recode

I need to change strings representing subject IDs into factors or anything more palatable than server database exported strings. The strings look like this:

"0762e6cc-2f79-49ab-9927-e708d7d191a3", "1c24e4a5-10df-48c8-a1e5-98690c25a0ab", etc.

I'd like them to look like the subject IDs we are using that come from a Qualtrics-type questionnaire. Those look like:

0001, 0002, etc.

It's easy enough to recode a factor into the latter, but I can't figure out to how to replace the strings with factors.

Please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We could either use `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements of the vector and then coerce to `integer` and then pad 0s at the beginning with `sprintf`

```
sprintf("%04d", as.integer(factor(v1, levels = unique(v1))))
#[1] "0001" "0002"
```

Or with `match`

```
sprintf("%04d", match(v1, unique(v1)))
#[1] "0001" "0002"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("0762e6cc-2f79-49ab-9927-e708d7d191a3", "1c24e4a5-10df-48c8-a1e5-98690c25a0ab")
```

Comment: I was having trouble getting this to work. I think I figured out a different way to do it based on a different suggestion. Check this out:

DF <- data.frame(ID = c(Level1$subject_id),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
summary(DF)
range(DF)
DF$ID <- factor(DF$ID)
DF$ID2 <- as.numeric(DF$ID)

Comment: @JoshMervis ok,  not clear what you meant.  sorry I showed a reproducible example

Comment: @JoshMervis Did yyou meant `Level$subject_id` as the 'v1' in my posst

Comment: @JoshMervis that example is not clear to me.  If you can  show a reproducible example and expected output, it would be great. thanks